# How to delete or remove the null value and field in JSON object which is returning by WCF service?

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I'm using WCF RESTful service to return JSON data to other platform. Now I have a problem about the return data. some of the field is needn't. And I didn't pass value to those field. But in the returning data, it will return a field:null . What I want to remove or delete those fields due to maybe it will waist much GPRS data.

Answer (score 2):

I found that .Net has already handle this. Just add a DataMemberAttribute for the fields: 
something like this: 
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
public string category;

Hope this can help others!
Happy Coding,
Rocky

Answer (score -1):

you can use below menioned code

```
  var jsondata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Value,Formatting.Indented,new JsonSerializerSettings() { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
```

Comment: We need more solutions on AJAX, JQUERY, Javascripts and something else.